# Batch file to map network drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, command

I need to create a bat file that will check availability of a drive letter and map the share folder on a free drive letter.

I tried to work something with an IF condition, but this prone to several drives mapping if the user launch it several time.

Can anyone help on how to use a FOR loop for this?

```
if not exist U:\ (
    net use U: \\test\branchshare$
exit
)
elseif not exist X:\ (
    net use X: \\test\branchshare$
exit
)
elseif not exist Y:\ (
    net use Y: \\test\branchshare$
exit
)
pause
```

Comment: `net use * \\test\branchshare$` takes the first free drive letter. To test if it is already connected, you can use `net use | find /i "\\test\branchshare$" && echo already connected`

Answer (score 0):

No need for a for-loop.
You can use `PUSHD` to assign a drive-letter to a network path and use `POPD` to release the driveletter when you are done.

example:

```
@echo off
echo %CD%
PUSHD \\test\branchshare$
echo %CD% 
POPD
echo %CD%
pause
```

See pushd /? and popd /? for details of these commands.

Comment: yes, but this is for using it as a temp measure to copy files. OP is actually trying to create actual shares for his users.

Answer (score 0):

Leeching of off [`@Stephans`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) comment, just to give it some more detail.

Using your method, or just `net use * \\host\share` will create a share each time you run it, it does not care if you have multiple instances, as long as it can assign a drive letter, it will. You can then use conditional operator to determine it for you as a one liner:

```
(net use | find /i "\\test\branchshare$")>nul 2>&1 && echo already connected || net use * "\\test\branchshare$"
```

The above uses `find` to to allow us to determine the result based on errorlevel. If successul (`errorlevel 0`) it means the find string was found and we simply say we did. If not found, `errorlevel 1`, it will perform the else operator.

The above can also be ran as:

```
(net use | find /i "\\test\branchshare$")>nul 2>&1 
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo already connected
  ) else (
    net use * "\\test\branchshare$"
)
```

So both these examples will only set the specific share once.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to work something out. thanks for your help guys

```
@echo off

CLS
net use | find /i "\\testfiler\test"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO 0002 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO 0001

:0001
echo.
echo The share folder is already available
echo.
pause
exit /b

:0002
net use * \\testfiler\test 
echo.
echo Share folder has been mapped successfully
echo.
pause
exit /b
```